# Gitlab Omnibus Latest Version | Sub Page on Apache

Tags: apache, gitlab, reverse-proxy, subdirectory

I am using the latest GitLab Omnibus package successfully. Now I am trying to use it with Apache as a subpage so I can run other webpages next to Gitlab.

I successfully managed to use Apache but I am an unable to call any other websites ( 403 ).

Setup Gitlab:

external_url 'http://server/gitlab'

nginx = false

nginx user = www-data

port 8181

Apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
  RewriteEngine on

  <Location /gitlab>
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://server/gitlab
  </Location>

    RewriteEngine on

    #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents
    #RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    #RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*


    RewriteRule  ^(.*)gitlab(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  # needed for downloading attachments
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/oldgit_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/oldgit_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/oldgit_access.log combined env=!dontlog

</VirtualHost>
```

As you might recognize , this is the basically the configuration file provided by Gitlab CE.

Gitlab does work as expected but I am not able to call any other web sides from apache ( /var/www/html/{subsite} ).

Error is 403

tried vhost file to give all the needed permissions ( granted all ), but the error persists.

Any experience with this scenario ?

Debain 8
Gitlab CE ( latest version )
Apache 2.4
  mod_rewrite 
  mod_proxy
  mod_proxy_http

Goal:

server/gitlab -> should pass all to Gitlab CE

server/{subsite} -> should just be handled by apache as usual

I guess it has something to do with the ReWrite rules, but not sure anymore .

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? Getting something similar with a 404 for anything outside gitlab.